# Custom filename QWEB report [ODOO 14.0]

Tags: pdf, odoo, report, odoo-14, qweb

I need a big help.

I need to change the report filename when the pdf is downloaded.

This is the button:

```
<button
   string="Generate Report"
   name="generate_report"
   type="object"
   class="btn-primary"
 />
```

This is the "generate_report" python function:

```
def generate_report(self):
        data = {
            'blabla': self.employee_id.name,
            'bla': self.employee_id.place_of_birth
        }

        return self.env.ref('module.action_generate_report').report_action(self, data=data)
```

And this is the action

```
<record id="action_generate_report" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Generate Report</field>
    <field name="model">custom.module</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">module.generate_report_template</field>
    <field name="report_file">module.generate_report_template</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">"Report - %s" % object.name</field>
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="paperformat_margin" />
</record>
```

If i use the "Print" button it works correctly, but if i use the custom button the solution above not work, everytime the file is downloaded, it has the name "Generate Report.pdf"

How to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do you print the report for one or more than one records?

Comment: please what? @KJ

Comment: I print the report for 1 record. The button is located in a tree view related to every single record @CZoellner

Comment: hmm, then it should work :-( i've no idea what is wrong. Try to debug `def report_download` of the web module, to get a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the `data` parameter, Odoo will not add the `active_ids` to the [report urls](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager_report.js#L187):

```js
if (_.isUndefined(action.data) || _.isNull(action.data) ||
   (_.isObject(action.data) && _.isEmpty(action.data))) {
   if (action.context.active_ids) {
       var activeIDsPath = '/' + action.context.active_ids.join(',');
       reportUrls = _.mapObject(reportUrls, function (value) {
           return value += activeIDsPath;
       });
   }
   reportUrls.html += '?context=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(session.user_context));
}
```

and then will fail to get the `docids` from it in the  [report_download](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L2098-L2103) controller:

```py
pattern = '/report/pdf/' if type == 'qweb-pdf' else '/report/text/'
reportname = url.split(pattern)[1].split('?')[0]

docids = None
if '/' in reportname:
    reportname, docids = reportname.split('/')
```

which is used to compute the report file name.

If [docids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L2119-L2124) is `None`, Odoo will not compute the report file name from `print_report_name` expression and will use the report name (`report.name`)

```py
if docids:
    ids = [int(x) for x in docids.split(",")]
    obj = request.env[report.model].browse(ids)
    if report.print_report_name and not len(obj) > 1:
        report_name = safe_eval(report.print_report_name, {'object': obj, 'time': time})
        filename = "%s.%s" % (report_name, extension)
```

You don't need to use `data` parameter, current record fields are accessible throw [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/reports.html#minimal-viable-template) variable. To fix this issue remove the `data` parameter or set it to `None` or `{}`